# Xamarin.Android app requires reinstallation after being idle for several days

Tags: android, xamarin, crash

I have a Xamarin.Android app that has been in production and stable for several years, but is now exhibiting crashing, during startup, when running on a specific device type (Zebra TC21/TC26), but only after it has been unused for 3 or 4 days.

If the app is used regularly, it performs reliably, but when left idle for an extended period, it crashes, during restart, apparently because Android has recycled the Application object, perhaps as [described here](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/).

The strange thing is that neither a forced close of the app nor a reboot of the device resolves the problem. Only after uninstalling and reinstalling the app will it run again.

To make matters worse, I can't seem to get any useful log data from the app when it is running on Zebra devices. The app is extensively instrumented for logging (via Loggly) and it works reliably for all other Android device types that I have tested, but Zebra test runs yield no log events.

I apologize that this is a vague question, but I have spent a huge amount of time trying to diagnose this issue and I am at a loss for what to try next. Any suggestions would be very welcome and I am happy to post more details, if required.

**UPDATE:** As suggested by @Cheesebaron, I have examined the device log, retrieved from a Zebra, which shows that the crash is due to an NRE. I attribute this to a required dependency not being injected correctly, but I am not sure what that tells me about the root cause of the problem, which clearly doesn't occur during normal operation. I am not an expert in deciphering Android logs, and I am curious what I should be looking for to understand the specific OS event that tipped the app into a failing state. Just being able to reproduce the issue in real time would be a great step forward.

I am also puzzled why this issue is not cleared by restarting the device. Does this indicate a data/settings corruption or could there be some other explanation? Is there anything in the device log that I should be looking for to understand this?

I am happy to post the device logs (or excerpts) if anyone feels inclined to review them.

Comment: Is there any way to get the device logs from the zebra and looking in those? Perhaps it has a hint as to why it fails to start again.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron for your suggestion. I have updated my question with some additional detail.